# Thesaurus software needed for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, thesaurus

**Can anyone recommend (free) Thesaurus software for Windows XP** (that isn't WordWeb)? It has to work with British English.

I want to install standalone software that gives me easy access (right click, keyboard shortcut or something) to alternatives to the selected word when I'm writing, whether it's an email, a text doc in notepad, on an internet forum or whatever.

I've tried WordWeb but found it pretty horrible - I want something that acts more like the Thesaurus in MS Word, giving a dozen or so decent alternatives to the selected word.

Comment: Do you realize that wordweb is built over one of the largest dictionaries available? Maybe if you search for other words... But wordweb thesaurus is rather complete and you will hardly get better than that.

Comment: I want half a dozen clear and relevant suggestions rather than a zillion presented so badly that it makes them incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

**[Mobysaurus](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Home-Education/Mobysaurus.shtml)** is a royalty-free, powerful and most suitable English thesaurus and dictionary

Mobysaurus Thesaurus is an offline, free English thesaurus software based on Moby Thesaurus II - royalty-free, authoritative and most suitable for everyday reference.

Mobysaurus Thesaurus will let you easily choose the right word/words whenever you want, for every occasion or purpose.

Here are some key features of "Mobysaurus":

A database that encompasses 30,260 roots and over 2.5 million synonyms

Wildcard word search

Look up history and bookmark your favorite words and phrases

Online search

Fast find related/synonyms roots

Full-text print and copy to clipboard

Suggest-as-you-type

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it looks horribly like WordWeb from the screenshots to me.